# How to copy data in same table with child and MasterID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have data in a SQL Server table like this:

```
PID   Name  RefNo       FID
----------------------------
1    ABC      G1
2    XYZ      G1          1 (1 relate to PID=1)
3    DEF      G1          1 (1 relate to PID=1)
```

To create a copy of above data in the same table for RefNO G2 we have used SQL query

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1 
    SELECT ISNULL(Max(PID),0) + 1, Name, 'G2', FID 
    FROM Table1
```

and it has copied the data like

```
1    ABC      G1
2    XYZ      G1          1 *(1 relate to PID=1)*
3    DEF      G1          1 *(1 relate to PID=1)*
4    ABC      G2
5    XYZ      G2          1 *(it should be 4 but it is showing 1 by my query)*
6    DEF      G2          1 *(it should be 4 but it is showing 1 by my query)*
```

Please guide how do I write the correct query to get my desired result as below

```
1    ABC      G1
2    XYZ      G1          1 
3    DEF      G1          1 
4    ABC      G2
5    XYZ      G2          4 
6    DEF      G2          4
```

Comment: That `INSERT` with that original data would *not* generate those results. If you're getting those results, it isn't by that statement.

Comment: Please guide me the Query  that Generate the desire result. I know my query is not correct.

Comment: We need more information here. What are your expected results?

Comment: as i mentioned in my question i need to get below result <br/>
PID   Name  RefNo       FID <br/>
1    ABC      G1<br/>
2    XYZ      G1          1 <br/>
3    DEF      G1          2 <br/>
4    ABC      G2<br/>
5    XYZ      G3          4<br/>
6    DEF      G3          5<br/>

Comment: [Edit] your question with your expected results.

Comment: Your example does not make sense.  As @larnu points out, the INSERT you posted (which uses NEWID) is not going to produce integer values in the resulting data.  NEWID generates a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, not an INT.  You need to update your post to reflect what you're really doing.

Comment: Although your question is not very clear i think i got it: what you need is to copy a tree with new ID's but preserving its internal structure, is that correct?

Comment: @Ilia Maskov Yes

Comment: @Umair then you should use a hierarchical recursive query for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create temporary table and insert data into it. below query help you do this.

```
create table #Temp
(
    PID int ,
    Name VARCHAR(100), 
    RefNo Varchar(50), 
    FID int 
)
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT * FROM temp1
```

Below Code help to insert data into main table using Cursor.

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(50),
        @FID INT,@TFID INT = NULL, 
        @RefNo VARCHAR(10) = 'G2' 
DECLARE cur CURSOR
FOR 
    SELECT Name ,FID
    FROM #Temp

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Name,@FID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN       
    IF @FID IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TFID = NULL
    END
    INSERT INTO temp1(Name,RefNo,FID)
    VALUES ( @Name, @RefNo, @TFID)
    
    IF @FID  IS NULL
    BEGIN
        SELECT @TFID = @@IDENTITY
    END
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Name,@FID
END
CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

After insert please delete #tTemp Table

```
drop table #Temp
```

You get updated main table.

Comment: @Danesh Patil
 It is copying Same FID for All records. like below
`PID Name RefNo FID 
1 Fabric1 Order1 NULL
2 Fabric2 Order1 NULL
3 Sub1Fabric1 Order1 1
4 Sub2Fabric1 Order1 1
5 Sub1Fabric2 Order1 2
6 Fabric1 G2 NULL
7 Fabric2 G2 NULL
8 Sub1Fabric1 G2 7
9 Sub2Fabric1 G2 7
10 Sub1Fabric2 G2 7 `

Comment: @Umair  Please arrange data entry as follows then above code should work

`PID Name RefNo FID  
1 Fabric1 Order1 NULL
2 Sub1Fabric1 Order1 1
3 Sub2Fabric1 Order1 1
4 Fabric2 Order1 NULL
5 Sub1Fabric2 Order1 4`